# Sum of list elements sums| Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to sum the results of list elements sum. I have this code:

```
adding_lists(List1, List2, Result) :- sumlist(list1, Result1), sumlist(list2, Result1), Result is Result1 + Result2.
```

but it returns false, what it's the way for this sum?

Comment: Do not ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted should have given you singleton warnings when consulted on your prolog interpreter.
Prolog is case sensitive. Furthermore, `List1`, which starts with a upper case letter, is a variable and `list1`, which starts with a lower case letter, is an atom.
So in your code you should have been warned that `List1`, `List2` and `Result2` are singleton variables (appear only once in the procedure).

Aside from that, you are issuing two calls to `sumlist/2` (presumably for `List1` and `List2` and unifying the result with the same variable `Result1`, whereas the second call should use `Result2`).

After fixing those issues you will end up with this code:

```
adding_lists(List1, List2, Result) :-
  sumlist(List1, Result1),
  sumlist(List2, Result2),
  Result is Result1 + Result2.
```

that should work fine.